# Send E-mail with python

Tags: python, django, email, signals

I need to always send the same file attached, but my signal is sending the full path of my server with my file.

e.g

/home/user/Sites/path_my_project/static/downloads/file.pdf

On my signal I get the file like this:

```
file_annex = ('path_my_file / myfile.pdf')
```

and sending the signal as follows:

```
EmailMessage message = (
         to = str (to),
         subject = subject,
         template = template,
         context = context,
         reply_to = _from,
         attachments = file_annex
     )
```

this works, but sends with of full path,i not understand why.
I want only send the file.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/#emailmessage-objects) `attachments` must be: *either email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase instances, or (filename, content, mimetype) triples.*

So you could try something like:

```
file_annex = ('myfile.pdf', open('path/to/myfile.pdf').read(), 'application/pdf')
```

Then you must pass `file_annex` as a single item in a list:

```
message = EmailMessage(
    ...
    attachments = [file_annex],
    ...
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `EmailMultiAlternatives` to send emails with Django, it's easier for me, if you want to try it, just do:

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives


subject = subject
from_email = 'from@example.com'
to = str(to)
text_content = 'This is an important message.'  # This is text message
html_content = template  # This is HTML message
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")

msg.attach_file('path_my_file / myfile.pdf')
msg.send()
```

- Don't forget the brackets `[ ]` around `to` because this allways have to be a list, even it's only 1 e-mail address (it could be more)
- There is **text_content** and **html_content** in case the receiver can't render html email

And you need in your ***settings.py*** your e-mail configuration:

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'any_mail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'email_pass'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

This configuration is good to send mails ***FROM*** gmail, if you use other email service, maybe you need to change some values.